# SAP Lumira Designer: How swap axis in Line Chart?

Tags: sap-lumira

How do you make the x-axis the y-axis and vice versa?

I have tried dragging the values in their respective axis in Chart Configuration but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Line charts cannot be switched on x and y axis.

This can be switched using Column & Bar charts. In SAP Lumira Bar charts have X-Axis as **Measures** and Y-Axis as **Dimensions**. Similarly, Column charts have Y-Axis as **Measures** and X-Axis as **Dimensions**.

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried that and ended up using a different chart. If anyone wanted that particular graph inverted, he just right-clicks on the graph and chooses Horizontal. SAP Lumira is very, very limited as far as graphs goes.